# Java libraries to read the Javadoc tags in classfile

Tags: javadoc

Are there any libraries which will read the Javadoc tags in a class file? Somewhat similar to qDox(http://qdox.codehaus.org/) but should be able to read the Javadoc tags.

Thanks!